# soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. The file does not exist

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, upgrade

We are upgrading SharePoint sites from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013 using Content DB attach. Upgrade from 2007 to 2010 works fine. When we upgrade from 2010 to 2013, site has a lot of issues.

List views shows a message that 'The web Page cannot be found'. 
NewForm/DispForm/EditForm of the lists are also missing. When I open the site using designer, I can see these files. When I try to open them I am getting this error message.

"soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. The file does not exist." 
Are we missing on something?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I could see the New/Edit/Display forms in the designer but couldn't open them. I resolved this issue by deleting the corrupt files and uploading the forms again from 2010 site.